# Using $scope in ui-router resolve

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I am using ui-router resolve in order to get some data from a service.

The thing is that I need to get a value from the parent $scope in order to call the service as shown bellow.

```
resolve: {
              contactService: 'contactService',
              contacts: function ($scope, contactService) {
                  return contactService.getContacts($scope.parentCtrl.parentObjectId);
              }
          }
```

I keep getting `Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!`

Also tried a few desperate attempts such as adding scope to the resolve object as shown bellow with not success.

```
scope: $scope
```

Any ideas?

Comment: can you post your code in plnkr?

Comment: I don't think my question needs any more explanation code, I simply want to add $scope to my ui-router's resolve.

Comment: What you are trying to do isn't possible.  If you need a value to be available to perform a calculation in the resolve function, it has to come from a service.

Comment: Since you are in need of the parent $scope variable I suspect you are capable of navigating to this state using some kind of parameter. This is the way to do this. Or you can inherit from the parent state and reuse the parent state's params.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That's impossible, scope hasn't been initialized at that point so you can't use it in the resolve object. You can access the scope in the controller after it's been initialized. The whole point of resolve is that it runs *before* controller initialization so that you can inject and directly access the resolved items in your scope.

If you need to pass a variable to the next state you can do that by using the `$stateParams` object which is available for use in resolve. You can add data to it when changing states, eg:

In your template, if you have a objectId in your scope:

```
<a ui-sref="statename({'id': objectId})">Change states</a>
```

Or in your controller:

```
$scope.go('statename', {'id': $scope.objectId});
```

You can then retrieve that in your resolve by using the `$stateParams`:

```
resolve: {
    contactService: 'contactService',
    contacts: function ($stateParams, contactService) {
        return contactService.getContacts($stateParams.id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly, but there are already instantiated scopes and controllers. How am I supposed to resolve a client's data if I don't have the client's ID for example?

Comment: You should pass that as a parameter to the next state, for instance: `$state.go('name'. {id: 1})` or `ui-sref="name({id: 1})"` and then inject `$stateParams` in your resolve to retrieve it again and fetch data based upon that

Comment: Now we are getting somewhere, thanks for the answer.

Comment: Read your problem and not really what you were trying to do, should have added that bit to my answer from the get-go, sorry for that, did that now for future users.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the accepted solution, which requires another round trip to the server for the same resource (if you are getting the value from the server/api) you could `$watch` the parent from the child controller.

```
function ParentController($http) {
  var vm = this;
  $http.get(someResourceUrl).then(function(res) {
    vm.someResource = res.data;
  });
}

function ChildController($scope) {
  // wait untill the parent gets the value
  var unwatch = $scope.$watch('parent.someResource', function(newValue) {
    if (newValue) {
      // the parent has the value, init this controller
      init(newValue);
      // dispose of the watcher we no longer need
      unwatch();
    }
  });
  function init(someResource) {
    // ... do something
  }
}

function routerConfig($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('parent', {
      url: '/parent',
      controller: 'ParentController',
      controllerAs: 'parent',
      templateUrl: '...',
    })
    .state('parent.child', {
      url: '/child',
      controller: 'ChildController',
      controllerAs: 'child',
      templateUrl: '...',
    });
}
```